# How do I combine two data-frames based on two columns?

Tags: r, merge, dataframe

I know I can use the `plyr` and its friends to combine dataframes, and `merge` as well, but so far I don't know how to merge two dataframes with multiple columns based on 2 columns?

Answer (score 176, accepted):

See the documentation on `?merge`, which states:

```
By default the data frames are merged on the columns with names they both have, 
 but separate specifications of the columns can be given by by.x and by.y.
```

This clearly implies that `merge` will merge data frames based on more than one column. From the final example given in the documentation:

```
x <- data.frame(k1=c(NA,NA,3,4,5), k2=c(1,NA,NA,4,5), data=1:5)
y <- data.frame(k1=c(NA,2,NA,4,5), k2=c(NA,NA,3,4,5), data=1:5)
merge(x, y, by=c("k1","k2")) # NA's match
```

This example was meant to demonstrate the use of `incomparables`, but it illustrates merging using multiple columns as well. You can also specify separate columns in each of `x` and `y` using `by.x` and `by.y`.

Comment: @darkage This question deals with merging data frames. Looks like you have data.tables. Totally different. I would read the documentation for data.table.

Answer (score 76):

Hope this helps;

```
df1 = data.frame(CustomerId=c(1:10),
             Hobby = c(rep("sing", 4), rep("pingpong", 3), rep("hiking", 3)),
             Product=c(rep("Toaster",3),rep("Phone", 2), rep("Radio",3), rep("Stereo", 2)))

df2 = data.frame(CustomerId=c(2,4,6, 8, 10),State=c(rep("Alabama",2),rep("Ohio",1),   rep("Cal", 2)),
             like=c("sing", 'hiking', "pingpong", 'hiking', "sing"))

df3 = merge(df1, df2, by.x=c("CustomerId", "Hobby"), by.y=c("CustomerId", "like"))
```

Assuming `df1$Hobby` and `df2$like` mean the same thing.

Answer (score 17):

You can also use the join command (dplyr).

For example:

```
new_dataset <- dataset1 %>% right_join(dataset2, by=c("column1","column2"))
```

Comment: For those who want to merge data frames and keep only the matching records by the columns specified, use `inner_join` instead `right_join`.