# R, replace values in a data.frame by values from another data.frame + dynamic columns

Tags: r

Best

Basically, I've a table *data* and a smaller table *vocabulary*.
What I would like to have is, that the values of the *vocabularies* well be mapped on the *data* values. And this within a function, in such a way that it can be used +/- dynamicaly

**Given:**

```
dt : data.csv
V1____V2___sex__V4__V5_
abc   abc  jeny abc 123
abc   abc  eric abc 123
abc   abc  bob  abc 123

vocabulary1: sex.csv
old___new
jeny  f
eric  m
bob   m
```

**Wanted Result:**

```
V1____V2___sex__V4__V5_
abc   abc  f    abc 123
abc   abc  m    abc 123
abc   abc  m    abc 123
```

**What I've**

```
replace_by_vocabulary <- function(dt,voc,col_name){
  dt[,col_name] <- tolower(dt[,col_name])

  **** something something ***

  return(dt)
}
```

**How I would like to use it ...**

```
dt <- replace_by_vocabulary(dt,vocabulary1,"sex")
dt <- replace_by_vocabulary(dt,vocabulary2,"date")
dt <- replace_by_vocabulary(dt,vocabulary3,"mood")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VLookup type method in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645222/vlookup-type-method-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to `merge` that is more in line with what you had:

```
replace_by_vocabulary <- function(dt,voc,col_name){
  col <- which(colnames(dt) == col_name)
  dt[,col] <- voc$new[match(tolower(dt[,col]), voc$old)]
  return(dt)
}
```

You want to locate the column in `dt` from the `col_name` string input first. Then, use `match` to find the row indices of `voc$old` that matches those of `tolower(dt[,col])`, and use these to retrieve the replacement values from `voc$new`. Here, we convert the `dt[,col]` column to all lower case, as you had in your sample code, dynamically in the function so as to match the lower case data in the vocabulary table. The advantage over `merge` is that we do not have to rename and remove columns afterwards to get the result you want.

Using your data:

```
replace_by_vocabulary(dt,vocabulary,"sex")
##   V1  V2 sex  V4  V5
##1 abc abc   f abc 123
##2 abc abc   m abc 123
##3 abc abc   m abc 123
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered merging, then dropping the unwanted column? Like so.

```
dt<-merge(x=dt, y=vocabulary1, by.x="sex", by.y="old")
dt<-dt %>% 
   select(-sex) %>% 
   mutate(sex=old)
```

Answer (score 1):

This post seems to be a duplicate of the one listed below.

[VLookup type method in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645222/vlookup-type-method-in-r)

You should be able to work out a function to do what you want to do using the merge function:

```
string = c("abc", "abc", "abc")
names = c("jeny", "eric", "bob")
sex = c("f", "m", "m")

data = data.frame(cbind(string, string, names, string, c(1, 2, 3)))
vocabulary1 = data.frame(cbind(names, sex))

dt = merge(data, vocabulary1, by.x = "names")
dt
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you aim correctly you want to merge two data.frames together?
You should look at `?merge`

For instance:

```
merge(x = dt, y = vocabulary1, by.x = "sex", by.y = "old")
```

If you want a dynamic function you could do

```
replace_by_vocabulary <- function(dt,voc,col_name){
    merged_df <- merge(x = dt, y = voc, by.x = "sex", by.y = col_name)
    return(merged_df)
}
```

Comment: no, the aim is to replace values from one column if they match the "old" column of the vocabulary table. but you cant do something like dt$["sex"] == voc$old <-- voc$new. or something

Comment: Then I think @aichao provided you a nice solution that you could accept.