# Matching values in a column using R - excel vlookup

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set in Excel with a lot of vlookup formulas that I am trying to transpose in R using the data.table package.

In my example below I am saying, for each row, find the value in column `y` within column `x` and return the value in column `z`.

The first row results in `na` because the value `6` doesn't exist in column `x`.

On the second row the value `5` appears twice in column `x` but returning the first match is fine, which is `e` in this case

I've added in the result column which is the expected outcome.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(x = c(1,2,3,4,5,5), 
y = c(6,5,4,3,2,1), 
z = c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"), 
Result = c("na", "e", "d", "c", "b", "a"))
```

Many thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645222/vlookup-type-method-in-r , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303283/how-to-do-vlookup-and-fill-down-like-in-excel-in-r

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can just use `match` to find the index of those matching elements of 'y' with that of 'x' and use that to index to get the corresponding 'z'

```
dt[, Result1 := z[match(y,x)]]
dt
#   x y z Result Result1
#1: 1 6 a     na      NA
#2: 2 5 b      e       e
#3: 3 4 c      d       d
#4: 4 3 d      c       c
#5: 5 2 e      b       b
#6: 5 1 f      a       a
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a join, but need to change the order first:

```
setorder(dt, y)
dt[.(x = x, z = z), result1 := i.z, on = .("y" = x)]
setorder(dt, x)
#   x y z Result result1
#1: 1 6 a     na      NA
#2: 2 5 b      e       e
#3: 3 4 c      d       d
#4: 4 3 d      c       c
#5: 5 1 f      a       a
#6: 5 2 e      b       b
```

I haven't tested if this is faster than `match` for a big data.table, but it might be.

Comment: Instead of sorting, there's `dt[, res := dt[.(y), on=.(x), z, mult="first"]]`

Comment: Just wondering what version of DT you are both using, I can't execute any of the above examples? I get `could not find function "."` for Rolands answer and an error on Frank's - `'on' argument should be a named atomic vector`
I am using 1.9.6 still

Comment: @MidnightDataGeek Obviously the current CRAN version. 1.9.6 is old.