# Merge data frames by exact match of column

Tags: r, dataframe, merge, conditional-statements, match

I would like to merge two data frames where one has more variables (columns) whereas the other has more observations (rows). A simplified example of how they are set up are below:

Dataframe 1:

```
ID      Date         Indicator
12345   01/01/2008   1
54321   12/01/2008   1
```

Dataframe 2:

```
ID      Date         
12345   01/01/2008   
12345   01/31/2008
12345   02/28/2009
24681   01/01/2008
54321   12/01/2008
54321   12/20/2008
```

What I would like to do is only keep the rows in which the ID's are an exact match. For example, I would like the following output:

New dataframe:

```
ID      Date         Indicator     
12345   01/01/2008   1
12345   01/31/2008   NA
12345   02/28/2009   NA
54321   12/01/2008   1
54321   12/20/2008   NA
```

I have tried

```
new <- merge(df1, df2, all=TRUE)
```

but this results in the merging of ALL rows, whereas I only want the rows from df2 with ID that are seen in df1.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: `merge(df1, df2, by="ID", all = TRUE)`  according to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/6709335/1719510

Comment: @Ryan sorry I changed it. Thank you

Comment: @foc, OP seems not want ID 24681, and seems that the join is also on date.

Comment: @s_t thank you. I didn't run into the results. Trying to learn answering.

Answer (score 2):

You can try with a `dplyr` solution:

```
library(dplyr)
# a right join when you filter Dataframe2 by ID in Dataframe1
Dataframe1 %>% right_join(Dataframe2[Dataframe2$ID %in% Dataframe1$ID,])  

Joining, by = c("ID", "Date")
     ID       Date Indicator
1 12345 01/01/2008         1
2 12345 01/31/2008        NA
3 12345 02/28/2009        NA
4 54321 12/01/2008         1
5 54321 12/20/2008        NA

# clearly you can put it in a data.frame
Dataframe3 <- Dataframe1 %>% right_join(Dataframe2[Dataframe2$ID %in% Dataframe1$ID,], by = 'ID') %>% 
             data.frame()
```

So you'll not have `ID` 24681 and you'll have NA in `Indicator` where it seems it's necessary, i.e. when `Date` does not want it.

---

Your data:

```
Dataframe1 <- read.table(text="ID      Date         Indicator
12345   01/01/2008   1
54321   12/01/2008   1", stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)

Dataframe2 <- read.table(text="ID      Date         
12345   01/01/2008   
12345   01/31/2008
12345   02/28/2009
24681   01/01/2008
54321   12/01/2008
54321   12/20/2008",stringsAsFactors = F, header = T)
```

Comment: I've tried it, but is going to give this      `ID       Date Indicator
1 12345 01/01/2008         1
2 54321 12/01/2008         1`, and it seems not what OP needs.

Comment: Hi @sh2 does this help you to solve the issue or do you need other help?

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
library(dplyr)
df2 %>%
  left_join(df1, by = c("ID", "Date")) %>% # or full_join(df1, by = c("ID", "Date"))
  filter(ID %in% df1$ID)
```

Or based on what you started:

```
merge(df1, df2, all = TRUE) %>% filter(ID %in% df1$ID)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the function join() from the ply library. You also require an extra step to get the exact output you need.

```
library(plyr)

df1

     ID       Date Indicator
1 12345 2020-01-01         1
2 54321 2020-12-01         1

 df2

     ID       Date
1 12345 2020-01-01
2 12345 2020-01-31
3 12345 2020-02-28
4 24681 2020-01-01
5 54321 2020-12-01
6 54321 2020-12-20

# that extra step
df3 <- df2[df2$ID %in% df1$ID,]
df3
     ID       Date
1 12345 2020-01-01
2 12345 2020-01-31
3 12345 2020-02-28
5 54321 2020-12-01
6 54321 2020-12-20

join(df3, df1, by = c("ID", "Date"))
     ID       Date Indicator
1 12345 2020-01-01         1
2 12345 2020-01-31        NA
3 12345 2020-02-28        NA
4 54321 2020-12-01         1
5 54321 2020-12-20        NA
```

Answer (score 1):

If your data size is not too large, you can add a line that filters your results by df1$id.

```
new <- new[new$id %in% unique(df1$id),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited based on s_t's comment:

```
left_join(df2, df1, by=c("ID", "Date")) %>% filter(ID %in% df1$ID)
```

Comment: This seems not give the desired result, as it's `ID Date Indicator 1 12345 01/01/2008 1 2 54321 12/01/2008 1`.

Comment: Yes, you are right! I misread the task `left_join(df2, df1, by=c("ID", "Date")) %>% filter(ID %in% df1$ID)` is correct. Which is quite similar to what you propose.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `merge` with `subset`:

```
df3 <- subset(merge(df1, df2, by=c("ID", "Date"), all=TRUE), ID %in% df1$ID)

df3
#      ID       Date Indicator
# 1 12345 01/01/2008         1
# 2 12345 01/31/2008        NA
# 3 12345 02/28/2009        NA
# 5 54321 12/01/2008         1
# 6 54321 12/20/2008        NA
```

To reset `row.names`, wrap the `data.frame()` constructor and specify row names argument:

```
df3 <- data.frame(subset(merge(df1, df2, by=c("ID", "Date"), all=TRUE),
                         ID %in% df1$ID),
                  row.names = NULL)

df3
#      ID       Date Indicator
# 1 12345 01/01/2008         1
# 2 12345 01/31/2008        NA
# 3 12345 02/28/2009        NA
# 4 54321 12/01/2008         1
# 5 54321 12/20/2008        NA
```

Answer (score 0):

a join is what you are looking for. If the table which you plan to keep as reference is on the left then its a left join. A sample code

```
    df1<-data.frame(ID=c(12345,54321) ,Date  =c('01/01/2008',' 12/01/2008 ')   ,    
     Indicator=c(1,1))

     df2<-data.frame(ID=c(12345,12345,5341) ,Date  =c('01/01/2008',' 12/01/2008 
      ','12/1/2008') )

    merge(df1,df2,by.x = 'ID',by.y='ID')

      ID     Date.x       Indicator       Date.y
      12345 01/01/2008         1    01/01/2008
      12345 01/01/2008         1    12/01/2008
```

So only the rows from df1 that are present in df 2 are part of the output